# Some advanced functionality of Apache's mod_rewrite?

Tags: html, apache, mod-rewrite

I have a website under `Apache2` that is accessible externally and internally through different URLs. It must work both at `example.com/` and `example.com/sites/mysite/`. Therefore, I am using relative URLs in my HTML, like:

```
../static/css/style.css
../some_other_page.html
```

In order to handle invalid requests to non-existing pages (e.g., `example.com/non_existing_page/`) I made a custom error page (which also contains links to other parts of the site) and used `mod_rewrite` to pass the requests there:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* /custom_404_page/ [PT]
```

As a result, the user sees the nicely customized page while the address bar still contains the original request. This rule can be also adapted according to the base URL. However, when making an invalid request to a subdirectory (e.g., `example.com/non/existing/page/`), the error page is broken, as the links are relative (e.g., `../static/css/style.css` resolves now to `example.com/non/existing/static/css/style.css`). I could fix this problem using `[R]` (redirect) flag instead of `[PT]`; however, then the address bar also reads `example.com/custom_404_page/`, which I would like to avoid.

Therefore, I wonder whether it is possible to retain all three functions while running under `Apache2`:

- Possibility to run at different base URLs
- Displaying a customized error page for invalid requests
- Retaining the original requests in the address bar

Comment: you may want to use `FallbackResource` instead, try it out.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way around, which would work for majority of websites:

```
Define MY_ROOT_BASE /sites/mysite/
Define MY_ROOT_PAGES "(static|index|some_page|some_another_page)"

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^${MY_ROOT_BASE}${MY_ROOT_PAGES}/ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule ^${MY_ROOT_BASE}(.*?/)?${MY_ROOT_PAGES}/(.*)$ ${MY_ROOT_BASE}$2/$3 [NC,R,L]
```

This will correct all requests that contain the name of one of the root pages but not in the root position. For example, `example.com/sites/mysite/some/rubbish/static/css/style.css` will become `example.com/sites/mysite/static/css/style.css`. The first rule is protecting the engine from the endless loop.

Note that if a request contains names of more than one root pages (e.g., `/index/some_another_page/`), it will trim unrecognized URL chunk only before the first match (due to the non-greedy `*?` in the pattern) and forward the request to the corresponding handler (in this example to the `/index/` handler). This behavior can be tweaked according to the needs of the specific website.